# MYSQL Only numbers can be inserted to table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have MySQL table called `cashreg` and it has only one row called also `cashreg` and is set to VARCHAR 64 and utf8_general_ci. The problem is that while using this form :

```
 <td>
<input placeholder="<?php echo SETTINGS_NEWCASHIER; ?>" class="form-control floating-label" name="newCashregInput" id="newCashreg" /></br>
<input style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="newCashreg" id="newCashreg" align="right" value="Pridėti kasos aparatą"></input>
</td>
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['newCashreg'])) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$table['cashreg']." VALUES (".$_POST['newCashregInput'].")");
}
```

the data from this form can be added to table if value is only made from numbers for example "984133" and for example "851fff", "gsdagsd", "fsdfas521" can't be added

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability warning, fix your code to use prepared statements

Comment: Stop using mysql_query, use PDO or mysqli.  Start using prepared statements, never put user input ($_POST) directly into the query.  Mysql reports errors when your query fails, gather those errors before coming here.

Comment: It's closed and old project, so I use mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the column name in your SQL query for inserting a record. see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Comment: Same problem with specified column

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you look into PDO. Your code is not safe.

But the answer to your question is qoutes. After concatenating the SQL statement it's wrong.
So the correct string should be `INSERT INTO cashreg VALUES ('value')`

You can insert number without a problem but if when you try to insert an alphanumeric string you need to quote it.
More info https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html

`<?php  if(isset($_POST['newCashreg'])) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table['cashreg']."VALUES('".$_POST['newCashregInput']."')");
}`

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
INSERT into tablename (columnx, columny, etc) VALUES ('valX', 'valY', 'etc')
```

Stop using the ancient mysql lib. It has been removed from PHP. Please instead use PDO. And prepared statements, your current code is vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.

https://phpdelusions.net/pdo